# jsf complex two-dimensional tree table component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I need to visualise complex hierarchical data (OLAP cube) using jsf. For simplicity assume that this is two-dimensional tree table. 
  First dimension is "time tree" (e.g. year - month), placed in X-Axis or "Columns place" of basic treetable. 
  Second is "product tree" (e.g. product - sub product), placed in Y-Axis where ordinary treetable's tree is placed.

See scheme below:

```
            |Y2013|           |Y2014|
            |  |___Sept__Dec  |  +  |
            |_____|_____|_____|_____|
Clothes     |2000 |1000 |1000 |2400 |
  |         |_____|_____|_____|_____|
  |__ Boots |1000 |500  |500  |1200 |
  |         |_____|_____|_____|_____|
  |__ Bags  |1000 |500  |500  |1200 |
            |_____|_____|_____|_____|
Souvenirs   |400  |200  |200  |500  |
  +         |_____|_____|_____|_____|
```

User can expand and collaps tree levels in both dimensions. For simplicity in Year 2013 two month is only shown. For example user can click any plus symbol to expand subtree. **Main problem is how to create additional tree in X-Axis (Columns names place)**.

**I need any ideas how to do this in JSF. I can use any Components libs and jsf implementations.**

Workaround:
  I have searched Oracle ADF, PrimeFaces, Apache Trinidad for "out of box" suitable components. I understand that I can create my own custom component, but it is time consuming solve. Also composite components could help but I have no idea how to use them to solve my problem, even in strategic view

Comment: hard one... this does not seem to be great but maybe http://sourceforge.net/p/olap-faces/wiki/Home/

Comment: Thanks to you I've found what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data tool name to provide such functionality is Pivot Table

- [Oracle ADF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24382_01/web.1112/e16181/dv_crosstab.htm) has great "out of box" Pivot Table with drilling
- [ZK framework](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zkpivottable) also provides some sort of Pivot Table.
- Leo's variant: http://sourceforge.net/p/olap-faces/wiki/Home/
- [Blog](http://blog.desarrolloagil.es/) about JSF/AngularJS replacement for JPivot based on olap4j. [Example](http://demo.desarrolloagil.es/olap-faces/test.jsf) (maybe out of date and maybe there is connection with this project and Leo's advice)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Pivot Table solution, there is a pure javascript pivot table component you could give it a try.

[Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com) is a web based pivot table implementation which provide full functions just like excel pivot table. And it can easily to be embedded into any web application. Here is [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents).